# Merging [burp] and [burpsuite]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Aren't these two tags actually the same thing?

[burp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burp), 57 questions, 9 followers:

> a popular platform for performing security testing of web applications. It can also be used by a malicious party to analyze and attack web applications. Implemented in Java.

[burpsuite](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burpsuite), 9 questions, 3 followers:

> a program used for security testing web applications.

Of these, 5 questions are tagged with both. Can we merge these two? Or is there some sublte difference that the tag excerpt does not pick up (or I don't understand)?

For the remaining tag, I think [burpsuite](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burpsuite) or perhaps [burp-suite](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burp-suite) would be a better name than just [burp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burp). But preferably with the tag excerpt of [burp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burp).

Comment: I agree. Burpsuite with the other description: "a popular platform for performing security testing of web applications. It can also be used by a malicious party to analyze and attack web applications. Implemented in Java."

Comment: @one Yeah, that tag excerpt is better. Added that to the question.

Comment: So far 17 upvotes, 0 downvotes. I think that settles it. Perhaps a moderator could come by and work their magic so this happends? Since I have 0 rep in the tag, I can not make synonym suggestions.

Comment: Done - merged, renamed, and wiki'd.